# Suspicious ethernet "connection established" despite not being plugged in

Tags: networking, ethernet

I just saw a the purple box in the right corner tell me I was connected to a network I've never seen before:

[image]

When I clicked on "Connection Information", I saw:
[image]

where the tab on the right is my normal WiFi.

I deleted the connection, and it told me my ethernet connection had now been disconnected.

This seems strange and possibly suspicious?

Comment: Do you run any VMs or VPNs?

Comment: Nope nothing of the sort that I know of

Comment: I seriously doubt you didn't see someone plug into your Ethernet plug from a mysterious location. It's normal. If they did, cut that cord! (or unplug it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enp0s25` is a network interface on your computer (an ethernet port).

You were given a 169.254.0.0/16 IP address, which is known as a [link-local address](https://serverfault.com/questions/427018/what-is-this-ip-address-169-254-169-254). This will usually happen when a network interface is "activated" but doesn't have a static IP and can't get a dynamic IP from the network.

I'd believe the most likely culprit is your driver (accidentally) thinking it was connected, or some script/similar tried to activate your network port with nothing plugged in. The connection itself is normally perfectly harmless, and deleting it seemed to take care of your issue.

If you're worried still, check your Ethernet port to make sure someone didn't plug anything in. It might even just need a bit of cleaning.

Comment: Thanks. I feel kind of silly for having asked this question, but I also had never seen the network pop up in my connected networks before so was a bit leery.

Answer (score 1):

Looks normal. Mine shows mine is

> Ethernet (enp0s31f6)